# Merge Error - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to use the `merge` function for the first time in sql server 2008 as follows:

```
MERGE PriceFeed AS t
USING Products AS src
ON t.sku = src.sku

WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
    SET src.price = t.price
;
```

But I'm getting the error `"The multi-part identifier "src.price" could not be bound."` and not sure why in this case?

The sku's in the feed data do match the sku's in the product table.

Comment: do u hav price column in ur  products table?

Comment: @Venk yeah there's def a price column in both tables

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522.aspx, you might need to correct the order in which you have put the tables: `MERGE Target AS T
USING Source AS S`

Answer (score 0):

```
MERGE PriceFeed AS t
USING Products AS src
ON t.sku = src.sku

WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
    SET t.price = src.price
;
```

Check the MERGE syntax here.. Its well explained here with examples.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/28/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-merge-statement-one-statement-for-insert-update-delete/

Comment: Is this wat ur looking for... U were setting the source column with ur target column.. it should be other way around..

Comment: Ha easy fix, I thought it looked correct setting the src equal to the t (feed) table but the other way around as you've suggested works?!

Comment: Patience ;-) I can't for a few more mins

Comment: I think that the target and products feed are the wrong way around as @diaho suggest so the answer is incorrect.

Comment: @aaron I was on a question ban... That was the reason I asked to accept the ans.. sorry will not ask from now onwards...